# Multiprobe LSH indexing Opencv

Tags: performance, opencv, indexing

I wrote a program that compares two images by taking both ORB descriptors and then comparing them using multiprobe LSH indexing:

```
flann::Index flannIndex(descriptorsA, flann::LshIndexParams(1,20,2), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);

flannIndex.knnSearch(descriptorsB, index, dist, 1, flann::SearchParams());
```

Which compares one input image with 10k images in 42 seconds (linear) retrieving good results.

--

Before I had

```
flann::Index flannIndex(descriptorsA, flann::LshIndexParams(10,10,2), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);

flannIndex.knnSearch(descriptorsB, index, dist, 1, flann::SearchParams());
```

Which with the same input and database, took 65 seconds also retrieving good results.

My question is more about the implementation of LSH: Why decreasing the number of tables and increasing the key size, makes the search faster? in other words:

Why

```
flann::Index flannIndex(descriptorsA, flann::LshIndexParams(1,20,2), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);
```

is faster than

```
flann::Index flannIndex(descriptorsA, flann::LshIndexParams(10,10,2), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);
```